# Injecting BeanFactory into a Bean

Tags: java, spring

I want to inject a Spring `BeanFactory` to a Bean created by the same `BeanFactory`
is the any way to do so?

by the way, I'm developing a web application.
If not I know that I can get the BeanFactory by having `RequestContext` but the bean I want to inject the `BeanFactory` is not in the `requestContext` but still in the application context. can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your bean can implement [`BeanFactoryAware`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryAware.html). By implementing this interface, your bean will receive the `BeanFactory` through a call to this method:

```
void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException
```

By the way, there is a similar interface (`ApplicationContextAware`) in order to retrieve the `ApplicationContext` if you need to.

Answer (score 18):

If annotation-config mode is enabled then this should work

```
class Bean
   @Autowired
   BeanFactory factory;
   ...
```