# Disable @EnableScheduling on Spring Tests

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, junit4, springjunit4classrunner

When I run my unit tests, it invokes my scheduled tasks. I want to prevent this behaviour, which is caused by the fact that I have `@EnableScheduling` on my main app configuration.

How can I disable this on my unit tests?

I have come across this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490617/spring-3-2-disable-cacheable-during-unit-tests) which suggests setting up profiles?

Not sure how I would go about that?  or if its an overkill?  I was thinking of having a separate AppConfiguration for my unit tests but it feels like im repeating code twice when I do that?

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(AppConfiguration.DAO_PACKAGE)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan({AppConfiguration.SERVICE_PACKAGE,
                AppConfiguration.DAO_PACKAGE,
                AppConfiguration.CLIENT_PACKAGE,
                AppConfiguration.SCHEDULE_PACKAGE})
public class AppConfiguration {

    static final    String MAIN_PACKAGE             = "com.etc.app-name";
    static final    String DAO_PACKAGE              = "com.etc.app-name.dao";
    private static  final  String ENTITIES_PACKAGE  = "com.etc.app-name.entity";
    static final    String SERVICE_PACKAGE          = "com.etc.app-name.service";
    static final    String CLIENT_PACKAGE           = "com.etc.app-name.client";
    static final    String SCHEDULE_PACKAGE         = "com.etc.app-name.scheduling";


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
       // stripped code for question readability
    }

    // more app config code below etc

}
```

Unit test example.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={AppConfiguration.class})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ExampleDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    ExampleDao exampleDao;

    @Test
    public void testExampleDao() {
        List<Example> items = exampleDao.findAll();
        Assert.assertTrue(items.size()>0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use spring context for unit testing?

Comment: so it autowires my objects so I can test my dao's and services?

Comment: You could just mock the Dao. Best would be use some framework like Mockito.

Comment: The correct answer is not in this thread, but found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226937/scheduled-method-is-called-during-the-tests

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you don't want to use profiles, you can add flag that will enable/disable scheduling for the application

In your `AppConfiguration` add this

```
  @ConditionalOnProperty(
     value = "app.scheduling.enable", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true
  )
  @Configuration
  @EnableScheduling
  public static class SchedulingConfiguration {
  }
```

and in your test just add this annotation to disable scheduling

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "app.scheduling.enable=false")
```

Comment: somehow it killed my spring boot configurations

Comment: Be aware that external components could be enabling scheduling automatically (see HystrixStreamAutoConfiguration and MetricExportAutoConfiguration from the Spring Framework). So if you try and use `@ConditionalOnProperty` or `@Profile` on the `@Configuration` class that specifies `@EnableScheduling`, then scheduling will be enabled anyway due to external components.     see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46783392/2947239

Comment: Sisyphus makes the same point I was going to make.  I would add that MetricExportAutoConfiguration comes from Spring Boot Actuator and cane be disabled in a test profile with : spring.metrics.export.enabled: false

Comment: As addition, you can set "app.scheduling.enable=false" in your application properties for tests, so that you don't need to add TestPropertySource annotation to each and every test.

Comment: If it kills whole application, annotate particular beans containing `@Scheduled` with `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "app.scheduling.enable", ... )` instead of of bean having `@EnableScheduling` annotation.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just move the `SchedulingConfiguration` out into its own class rather than be a static inner class, and drop the `@ConditionalOnProperty`. This will get picked up automatically if you use `@SpringBootApplication` but will get ignored by the tests. Note, you might have to tweak your scan paths to find the configurations.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.13/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config

Answer (score 38):

I just parameterized my @Scheduled annotation with configurable delay times:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${timing.updateData}", initialDelayString = "${timing.initialDelay}")
```

In my test application.yaml:

```
timing:
    updateData: 60000
    initialDelay: 10000000000
```

And main application.yaml:

```
timing:
    updateData: 60000
    initialDelay: 1
```

It's not turning it off but creating such a long delay, the tests will be long over before it runs. Not the most elegant solution but definitely one of the easiest I've found.

Comment: Not a clean solution. but it does its work. Have an up-vote just for this different angle

Comment: Out of the box thinking and also taught me a configuration I can use throughout my sever for setting a general fixed delay... Fantastic if you ask me :)

Answer (score 30):

One more solution without any change in production code, using the `@MockBean`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@MockBean(MyScheduledClass.class)
public class MyTest {
```

Which will eventually replace active scheduled job or create a mocked one.

From the documentation

> Mocks can be registered by type or by {@link #name() bean name}. Any existing single
>     bean of the same type defined in the context will be replaced by the mock, if no
>     existing bean is defined a new one will be added.

Comment: Very nice, best answer 

Comment: But the question is how to disable the scheduling mechanism alone, as per your answer, the whole bean will be mocked, we cannot even use it as a normal spring bean. For me, @Laila Sharshar answer worked correctly

Comment: This is by far the best and IMHO most clean answer. I always split out scheduling into a thin separate layer (i.e., an extra bean) to separate concerns, anyway, so @PrasanthRajendran comment doesn't apply to me.

Comment: Keeping the scheduling in a separate bean is indeed a very good practice, otherwise single responsibility principle is not maintained properly. Thanks for explicitly mentioning that @StefanHaberl

Answer (score 21):

An alternative would be to unregister the bean post processor that schedules the events. This can be done by simply putting the following class on the classpath of your tests:

```
@Component
public class UnregisterScheduledProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class)) {
            ((DefaultListableBeanFactory)beanFactory).removeBeanDefinition(beanName);
        }
    }
}
```

While this is quite simple and seems to do the job, beware that I did not test this very much or check for possible implications of removing a defined bean from the registry or making sure that ordering of PostProcessors won't be an issue...

Comment: Just to give some feedback - I just tried this method and it appears to work just fine.

Comment: I have tried @vojtech-ruzicka and @lolotron answers plus other answers on [this similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226937/scheduled-method-is-called-during-the-tests)
  

Likewise I must add that only @yankee answer worked for me.  With a `@Configuration` annotation on his example `UnregisterScheduledProcessor ` class for it to be auto loaded by Spring under my test.  So far I have not experience any issues with it.

Comment: This was the best solution for me, as I preferred not to modify existing production code just for the sake of tests.  I simply added this to my test classpath as a Spring @Component, and it's working so far, great solution!

Comment: To reference the BeanFactory for the above solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487595/injecting-beanfactory-into-a-bean

Comment: This solved it for me. Thanks! Attention, as I need to annotate the class with @Component. That's all that was missing.

Answer (score 19):

With Spring Boot and cron expression you can enable or disable scheduling.
For example you can define an test application.yml and set

```
scheduler:
  cron-expr: '-'
```

See also [disable scheduling with '-'](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--).
In your scheduler class you can pass the expression.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler.cron-expr}")
```

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer; it's so much better than everything else listed here

Answer (score 5):

Discovered that adding

> app.scheduling.enable=false

in test application.properties along with

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "app.scheduling.enable", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@EnableScheduling
```

to scheduling configuration class annotations like in [Marko Vranjkovic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42597467/14678441) works for all tests without need to annotate each of them!

Answer (score 2):

In each Test you define which spring configuration should be used, currently you have:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={AppConfiguration.class})
```

Common practice is to define separate spring configuration for your normal application and for your tests.

```
AppConfiguration.java 
TestConfiguration.java
```

Then in your test you simply refference `TestConfiguration` instead of your current `AppConfiguration` using `@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestConfiguration.class})`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestConfiguration.class})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ExampleDaoTest
```

This way you can configure any setting for your tests differently than in production code. You can for example use in-memory database for your tests instead of regular one and much more.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work that way. The test uses the TestConfiguration class but it still also uses the annotations declared on the TestConfiguration. :(

Comment: You may set up a test configuration class or an active profiles to pick up from the properties file, however by doing this you don't avoid the annotated class being scheduled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226937/scheduled-method-is-called-during-the-tests - This one worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a method that removes the scheduled tasks during unit tests.
Here is an example:

```
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

    public static void removeScheduledTasks(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor postProcessor, ApplicationContext appContext) {
        postProcessor.setApplicationContext(appContext);
        postProcessor.getScheduledTasks().forEach(ScheduledTask::cancel);   
    }
}
```

Use example:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.example.Utils;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestRemoveScheduller {

    
    @Autowired
    private ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor postProcessor;
    
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;


    @Before
    public void init(){

        //Some init variables
        
        //Remove scheduled tasks method
        Utils.removeScheduledTasks(postProcessor, appContext);
        
    }

    //Some test methods

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The way that I have solved this is for spring boot applications is by disabling the @EnableScheduling configuration for the test profile:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@Configuration
@Profile({"!test"})
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingConfiguration {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do this in a normal class (not a unit test).  I have my main Spring Boot application but needed a small utility class to do some bulk data cleanup.  I wanted to use the full application context of my main app but turn off any scheduled tasks.  The best solution for me was similar to Gladson Bruno:

```
scheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getScheduledTasks().forEach(ScheduledTask::cancel);
```

Another advantage of this approach is you can get a list of all scheduled tasks, and you could add logic to cancel some tasks but not others.

Answer (score 1):

create `TestTaskScheduler` Bean in test class

```java
public class TestTaskScheduler implements TaskScheduler {
    
    private static final NullScheduledFuture NULL_SCHEDULED_FUTURE = new NullScheduledFuture();
    
    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger) {
        return NULL_SCHEDULED_FUTURE;
    }

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable task, Date startTime) {
        return NULL_SCHEDULED_FUTURE;
    }

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Date startTime, long period) {
        return NULL_SCHEDULED_FUTURE;
    }

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, long period) {
        return NULL_SCHEDULED_FUTURE;
    }

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, Date startTime, long delay) {
        return NULL_SCHEDULED_FUTURE;
    }

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, long delay) {
        return NULL_SCHEDULED_FUTURE;
    }
    
    private static class NullScheduledFuture implements ScheduledFuture {
        
        @Override
        public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Delayed o) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCancelled() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDone() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Object get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can simply `@MockBean TaskScheduler taskScheduler;`

Answer (score 0):

I would go for TestExecutionListener,
example:

```
public class SchedulerExecutionListener implements TestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(@NonNull TestContext testContext) {
        try {
            ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor schedulerProcessor = testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class);
            schedulerProcessor.destroy();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ignored.getMessage());
        }
}
```

And then you add it to ur testClass

```
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = SchedulerExecutionListener .class, mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
class Test {}
```

Answer (score 0):

My application properties are stored in `application.yml` so simple add ConditionalOnProperty to scheduler:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "scheduling.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@EnableScheduling
```

And disable develop environment in `application.yml`:

```
environments:
    development:
        scheduling:
            enabled: false
```