# Disable Spring @EnableScheduling in Junit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I want to disable @Schedule in Spring tests but i can`t find a way to do it.

I have tried to make different config class for test environment but tasks are still fired.
This is config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan({"de.package"})
@PropertySource(name="application.properties", value="classpath:application.properties")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {
...
}
```

This is test emvironment config.Just removed @EnableScheduling annotation

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"de.package"})
@PropertySource(name="application.properties", value="classpath:application.properties")
public class PersistenceJPATestConfig {
...
}
```

In test i use:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { PersistenceJPATestConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class GetArticlesTest {
...
}
```

But tasks are still fired when i run the test..Is there any way to stop executing tasks while running tests ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable @EnableScheduling on Spring Tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014496/disable-enablescheduling-on-spring-tests)

Answer (score 5):

As you're using @ComponentScan on the same package both time, it seems spring is loading the other configuration too.

You could use some profile to filter that, like adding this on your PersistenceJPATestConfig

```
@Profile("test")
```

add this annotation on your JUnit class so it will be executed with the "test" profile

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

Edit :
Your main config should also be profiled so it is ignored when its profile is not active, so you should add another @Profile on the main config class with a different profile than "test"

Comment: There are multiple duplicates to this question with different answers. This is the only valid one in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution based on other answers(for spring boot users), just add below code to main configuration so that it wont run on test profiles and test cases! No other changes!

```
@Profile(!test)
public class Config{
......
}
```