# Scheduled method is called during the tests

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I'm developing a SpringBoot application using Maven.

I've a class with the `@Component` annotation which has a method `m` with the `@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 5000)` annotation. Here `fixedDelay` can be set to *specify the interval between invocations measured from the completion of the task*.

I've also the `@EnableScheduling` annotation in the main class as:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class FieldProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FieldProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Now whenever I run the tests, defined as :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BankitCrawlerTests {

...

}
```

the scheduled task `m` is also run every 5 seconds.

Of course I just want to run the scheduled task whenever the application runs. How can I do it (i.e. prevent the scheduled task to run when a test is run)?

Answer (score 26):

You can extract `@EnableScheduling` to a separate configuration class like:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!test")
@EnableScheduling
class SchedulingConfiguration {
}
```

Once it's done, the only thing that is left is to activate "test" profile in your tests by annotating test classes with:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

Possible drawback of this solution is that you make your production code aware of tests.

Alternatively you can play with properties and instead of annotating `SchedulingConfiguration` with `@Profile`, you can make it `@ConditionalOnProperty` with property present only in production `application.properties`. For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "scheduling.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    @EnableScheduling
    static class SchedulingConfiguration {

    }
}
```

Scheduler will not run in tests when you do one of following:

- add property to `src/test/resources/application.properties`:

  scheduling.enabled=false
- customize `@SpringBootTest`:

  `@SpringBootTest(properties = "scheduling.enabled=false")`

Comment: Did you understand that I don't want scheduling in my tests? Does `@Profile("!test")` mean _not_ in the tests?

Comment: It means that configuration class will be created if "test" profile is not active.

Comment: What do you think about [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014496/disable-enablescheduling-on-spring-tests)? I've never created specific configurations (apart from annotating the main class with `@SpringBootApplication`). Where should I put new configurations, in general?

Comment: New configuration classes can be placed in the root package of your project or any subpackage - that depends on what is configured and what is the package structure. In case of scheduling - which is usually used globally for whole application I would put it to root package or even better as a static inner class of `FieldProjectApplication`.

Comment: Regarding solution from another answer, you can have separate configuration classes for production and test code, but if possible I would avoid it and aim to keep test and production config as close as possible. That again heavily depends on the size and structure of your application.

Comment: Could you please give a code example of your second approach with `@ConditionalOnProperty`? By the way, this `SchedulingConfiguration` class could then be placed as an inner class of the main class, i.e. the class with the  `@SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! On the other hand, it doesn't seem work. I've tried either by having `@SpringBootTest(properties = "scheduling.enabled=false")` or setting `scheduling.enabled=false` in `src/test/resources/application.properties`, and a scheduled method with the following signature `@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 50000000)` still seems to be executed. I don't know what could be causing it to run, also because it runs just during 1 test class, which makes all this even more strange, because, as far as I've understood, the scheduled should run by default on all tests...

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier if you could reproduce it in sample project on github.

Comment: I would definitely, but I can't, since I'm working on a project which not mine..

Comment: The way I described it in the answer definitely works - meaning you can enable/disable particular configuration classes using profiles or properties - so problem has to be specific to your project. Maybe `@EnableScheduling` is used also somewhere else in your project?

Comment: I have the same issue and the propsed solution does not work for me.  I even removed `@EnableScheduling` completely but the scheduling was still triggered. It seems some dependecy automatically add `@EnableScheduling`. It is discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43204377/spring-boot-scheduler-runs-without-enablescheduling-annotation