# Spring-boot scheduler runs without @EnableScheduling annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was following this example to create a scheduled task in a sample project:  https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks

It says, `@EnableScheduling ensures that a background task executor is created. Without it, nothing gets scheduled.`

But, by mistake i didn't use it. How come it still works?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Other Classes:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
 }

@Component
public class ScheduledTaskRunner {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTaskRunner.class);

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/1 * * * * *")
    public void run(){
        log.info("Hello");
    }
}
```

Isn't the scheduled task supposed to not run?

Comment: Because of the inclusion of the `actuator`... That has a scheduler to periodically export the metrics using a `MetricsWriter`. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/MetricExportAutoConfiguration.java (which was added in Boot 1.3.0).

Comment: As of Spring Boot 2, `actuator` does not enable the scheduling by default anymore, so you will need to make sure you have `@EnableScheduling` in your configuration. See details here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8040

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code added the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` when that is added a scheduler is added as well. This scheduler is used by the actuator to schedule the automatic export of the metrics.

The code for this is in the [`MetricExportAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/MetricExportAutoConfiguration.java) and has been added in Spring Boot 1.3.0.

So if you remove the actuator scheduling won't work anymore.

Comment: spring-session will [add](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/090a10fb1032d27d1be9fd7a34d99a57efc261ef/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java#L350) `@EnableScheduling` too.

Comment: In my case, `spring-session-data-redis` caused this behavior.