# How the scheduler is running without @EnableScheduling annotation in the project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application, which is referring/depends on other Jar.
The Jar is basically a Spring application which as a scheduler method in it.

I don't have any @EnableScheduling annotation on the Spring Boot application and in the external Jar also.

But as soon as I run the Spring Boot, the scheduler kicks in.

I am not understanding without @EnableScheduling annotation what is causing the scheduler to start execution.

i gone through the below answer from M. Deinum, he says @EnableScheduling will be added as part of springboot actuator (version 1.3.0).

[Spring-boot scheduler runs without @EnableScheduling annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43204377/spring-boot-scheduler-runs-without-enablescheduling-annotation)

Yes I have a Spring Boot actuator in my classpath and the version of Spring Boot I am using is 2.0.3.

How can I discover which component is causing the scheduling to kick in? And the possible way to avoid the Scheduling.

Comment: THat is already answered in the question you linked. Adding the actuator is enabling scheduling.

Comment: @M. Deinum Is auto EnableScheduling from actuator not disabled from 2.x onwards ? Also let me know is there any possible way to find out which class is enabling the EnableScheduling functionality.

Comment: without knowing what your dependencies are, that is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using Spring Boot, it will configure the project automatically according to your class path and configuration classes. Then you just happened to have spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency in your class path, one of the feature in spring-boot-starter-actuator is scheduled tasks. (Actuator @Configuration class had already add @EnableScheduling, so Spring Boot will detect it and configure it to your project, after that your project will also have this feature either).

But as Spring Boot 2, actuator does not enable the scheduling by default, I cannot replicate this issue in my environment, I'm using 2.2.5.RELEASE, so maybe update your spring boot version will help to avoid this.

---

I cannot reproduced your case in my environment with spring boot 2.0.3. Below is my code snippet.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ouyang</groupId>
    <artifactId>Testing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Store</name>
    <description>Testing</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void test() {

        System.out.println("HI");

    }

}
```

@Scheduled method test() is not invoked.

Comment: i am using is 2.0.3, do u think it enables scheduling by default?

Comment: No, with spring boot 2.0.3, actuator does not enable the scheduling by default.

Comment: Thank you.  can u  let me know is there any possible way to find out which class is enabling the EnableScheduling functionality.

Comment: MetricExportAutoConfiguration, FYI https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricExportAutoConfiguration.html