# Disable @Schedule on Spring Boot IntegrationTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, automated-tests, spring-scheduled

How can I disable the schedule auto-start on Spring Boot IntegrationTest?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally enable or disable scheduled jobs in Spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406713/how-to-conditionally-enable-or-disable-scheduled-jobs-in-spring)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable @EnableScheduling on Spring Tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014496/disable-enablescheduling-on-spring-tests)

Comment: I can't believe there's no good answer to this question.  Very surprising.

Comment: The only solution I got to work was to use the @Profile - annotation, by creating a test profile and a production profile. ProTip: Do not forget to activate the production profile in your src/main/resources/application.properties if you want to avoid your colleagues hating you. ;)

Answer (score 22):

Be aware that external components could be enabling scheduling automatically (see [HystrixStreamAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/stream/HystrixStreamAutoConfiguration.java#L53) and [MetricExportAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8040) from the Spring Framework). So if you try and use `@ConditionalOnProperty` or `@Profile` on the `@Configuration` class that specifies `@EnableScheduling`, then scheduling will be enabled anyway due to external components.

### One solution

Have one `@Configuration` class that enables scheduling via `@EnableScheduling`, but then have your scheduled jobs in separate classes, each of those using `@ConditionalOnProperty` to enable/disable the classes that contain the @Scheduled tasks.

Don't have the `@Scheduled` and `@EnableScheduling` in the same class, or you will have the issue where external components are enabling it anyway, so the `@ConditionalOnProperty` is ignored.

Eg:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApplicationSchedulingConfiguration {
}
```

and then in a separate class

```
@Named
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "scheduling.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class MyApplicationScheduledTasks {

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60 * 60 * 1000)
  public void runSomeTaskHourly() {
    doStuff();
  }
}
```

The issue with this solution is that every scheduled job needs to be in it's own class with `@ConditionalOnProperty` specified. If you miss that annotation, then the job will run.

### Another Solution

Extend the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` and override the `TaskScheduler` methods. In these methods you can perform a check to see if the job should run.

Then, in your @Configuration class where you use @EnableScheduling, you also create a @Bean called taskScheduler which returns your custom thread pool task scheduler).

Eg:

```
public class ConditionalThreadPoolTaskScheduler extends ThreadPoolTaskScheduler {

  @Inject
  private Environment environment;

  // Override the TaskScheduler methods
  @Override
  public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger) {
    if (!canRun()) {
      return null;
    }
    return super.schedule(task, trigger);
  }

  @Override
  public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable task, Date startTime) {
    if (!canRun()) {
      return null;
    }
    return super.schedule(task, startTime);
  }

  @Override
  public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Date startTime, long period) {
    if (!canRun()) {
      return null;
    }
    return super.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, startTime, period);
  }

  @Override
  public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, long period) {
    if (!canRun()) {
      return null;
    }
    return super.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, period);
  }

  @Override
  public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, Date startTime, long delay) {
    if (!canRun()) {
      return null;
    }
    return super.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, startTime, delay);
  }

  @Override
  public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable task, long delay) {
    if (!canRun()) {
      return null;
    }
    return super.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, delay);
  }

  private boolean canRun() {
    if (environment == null) {
      return false;
    }

    if (!Boolean.valueOf(environment.getProperty("scheduling.enabled"))) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Configuration class that creates the taskScheduler bean using our custom scheduler, and enables scheduling

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApplicationSchedulingConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
    return new ConditionalThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
  }
}
```

The potential issue with the above is that you've created a dependency on an internal Spring class, so if there are changes in the future, you'd have to fix compatibility.

Comment: I have made mine work with the 1st solution. Thanks!

Comment: I just have my own flag in doStuff I make the check, if its not enabled then do nothing, let schedulars run, they end up doing nothing

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to use `@ConditionalOnProperty` on the Configuration class, but does not work this way.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. Tried Spring's `@ConditionalOnProperty` attribute with my Scheduling Bean but Scheduling still got activated in tests.

The only good workaround I found was to overwrite the scheduling properties in the Test class, so that the job does not have a **real** chance to run.

If your real job runs every 5 minutes using property `my.cron=0 0/5 * * * *`

```
public class MyJob {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron}")
    public void execute() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Then in the test class you can configure it as:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"my.cron=0 0 0 29 2 ?"}) // Configured as 29 Feb ;-)
public class MyApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

So even if your job is activated, it will only run at the 0th hour of 29 Feb which happens once in 4 years. So you have a very slim chance of running it.

You can come up with more fancy cron settings to suit your requirements.

Comment: You could also set the cron value to `-` via properties, as this is reserved expression meaning never run

Answer (score 5):

An easy solution I figured out in Spring Boot 2.0.3:

1) extract scheduled method(s) to a separate bean

```
@Service
public class SchedulerService {

  @Autowired
  private SomeTaskService someTaskService;

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60 * 60 * 1000)
  public void runSomeTaskHourly() {
    someTaskService.runTask();
  }
}
```

2) mock the scheduler bean in your test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeTaskServiceIT {

  @Autowired
  private SomeTaskService someTaskService;

  @MockBean
  private SchedulerService schedulerService;
}
```

Comment: disable @Schedule service on Spring Boot Test, by mocking its bean

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use Spring profiles

In your test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
public class SpringBootTestBase {
    ...
}
```

In your scheduler class or method:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!integration-test") //to disable all from this configuration
public class SchedulerConfiguration {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${some.cron}")
    @Profile("!integration-test") //to disable a specific scheduler
    public void scheduler1() {
        // do something
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${some.cron}")
    public void scheduler2() {
        // do something
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: pretty bad if you have many tests written by other people.

Answer (score 1):

When your real Spring Boot Application class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication   
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

you would have to create another Application class without @EnableScheduling for your integration tests like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication   
public class MyTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And then use the MyTestApplication class in your integration test like this

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyTestApplication.class)
public class MyIntegrationTest {

...
}
```

That's the way I do it, since I have not found a better way.

Comment: This will only work in very special setups. Since `@SpringBootApplication` includes the `@ComponentScan` annotation, even if you specify MyTestApplication to be used by your tests, usually the `@ComponentScan` part is going to find the other class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` apply its configuration as well and voila your `@EnableScheduling` is back on. For this to work you need to have both classes in different packages on the same level, which makes the whole auto configuration useless.

Comment: Yes this looked so promising then as @ali suggest `@EnableScheduling` still kicked it

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using a separate configuration class and then overwrite this class in the test context. So instead of putting the annotation at the application I only put it at the separate configuration classes.
Normal context:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling 
public class SpringConfiguration {}
```

Test context:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Integrating some answers from above:

- Create a separate configuration class for testing purposes (a.k.a "TestConfiguration.class")
- Enable Mockito annotations there for other beans: schedulers, etc.  `- Read this: 2)`

  ```
  @ConditionalOnClass
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean
  @ConditionalOnBean
  @ConditionalOnJava
  @ConditionalOnJndi
  @ConditionalOnMissingClass
  @ConditionalOnExpression
  @ConditionalOnNotWebApplication
  @ConditionalOnWebApplication
  @ConditionalOnProperty
  @ConditionalOnResource
  @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate
  ```

Plus, always checking:

- "application.yml" self-creation properties depending on external devices/services
- Auto-configuration annotations on Main class breaking beans initialization sequence
- "applicationContext.xml", "beans.xml" or Classpath loaders

Please, read these:

- 1) [SpringBoot Auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html)
- 2) [How Spring Boot Autoconfiguration works](https://medium.com/empathyco/how-spring-boot-autoconfiguration-works-6e09f911c5ce)
- Try using mocking annotation on non-required beans for testing such as:

  ```
  @MockBean
  private StoresRatingAvgScheduler scheduler;

  @Before
  public void init() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }
  ```