# how to ignore schedulled task when execute junit test method

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

Spring boot(2.2.4),

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Slf4j
class FooServiceImplTest {
    @Test
    void foo(){...}
}
```

because there is a class(`MyJob.class`) with `Scheduled` Annotation

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
```

so when execute foo test, it will execute the scheduled task, and could see below logger

```
[2022/05/26 21:21:13] [main] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  171 - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[2022/05/26 21:21:14] [main] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler  171 - Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
[2022/05/26 21:21:14] [main] INFO  c.b.p.s.i.FooServiceImplTest  61 - Started FooServiceImplTest in 3.634 seconds (JVM running for 4.332)

[2022/05/26 21:21:14] [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler  208 - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
[2022/05/26 21:21:14] [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  208 - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

How to ignore scheduled task conveniently? e.g.

```
@DisableScheduling 
class FooServiceImplTest {
```

or

```
@IgnoreClass(MyJob.class)
class FooServiceImplTest {
```

Now when I execute test method, I manually explicitly comment `EnableScheduling` first

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DruidDataSourceAutoConfigure.class)
//@EnableScheduling
public class FooApplication {
```

Comment: do you have a `@Configuration` class. If yes please add the code in question

Comment: have a look here: [disable-enablescheduling-on-spring-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014496/disable-enablescheduling-on-spring-tests)